# Figures and table side by side using the whole page width

Tags: sidebyside

Currently I am making a design/layout on LaTeX for some specific kind of reports and I am struggling a little bit to achieve something. I want to add a figure, a table with some information and another figure, all side by side, but I want them to use the whole page width instead of the text width.

I could say that I managed to make it, but I feel it's more like a workaround, so I wanted to know if there is a more consistent way of achieving it, where I can specify (to some extent) a place for each element to be placed. I tried using `minipage`, for example, but I didn't really succeed and all topics I found concerning a similar problem consider the text width.

The way I am doing it now is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={160mm,200mm},showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\makebox[\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \raisebox{1.4cm}{
    \small{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        Street, number \\
        Postal Code, City \\
        Country \\[0.3cm]
        email@email.com\\
        www.website.com
    \end{tabular}}}
    \hspace{3mm} \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth, height=0.15\textheight]{example-image-b}
}

\end{document}
```

Any input will be very appreciated! Also if this way I am doing it is fine, I would be glad to hear from someone else! :)

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you want to change in your output -- a handrawn sketch could clarify

Comment: @jsbibra thanks for the answer! Actually the output is fine... my doubt is whether there is a better way to achieve the same output (the three elements side by side occupying more than the `textwidth`), because I think my approach is not consistent... I have to adjust the positions with `\hspace` every time I want to change something and I always have the warning "overful \hbox". P.S.: sorry for not adding images. I tried to but then the only option is to insert a link.

Comment: Probabyl using the `changepage` package could help here?

Comment: @leandriis definitely helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package and `valign=c` from `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={160mm,200mm},showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{changepage} % for the adjustwidth environment
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % offers the valign option

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{-2.5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a}
    \hfill
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        Street, number \\
        Postal Code, City \\
        Country \\[0.3cm]
        email@email.com\\
        www.website.com
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth, height=0.15\textheight, valign=c]{example-image-b}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Small variation of @leandriis [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554410/figures-and-table-side-by-side-using-the-whole-page-width/554422#554422) (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            total={160mm,200mm},
            showframe
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-25mm}{-25mm}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=24mm}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}
                            p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                            p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                            p{\dimexpr0.50\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                             @{}}
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    &   \small
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
        Street, number \\
        Postal Code, City \\
        Country \\[0.3cm]
        email@email.com\\
        www.website.com
        \end{tabular}
        &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with you for the +1 :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you! Now I slightly improve my design ... so it is now nicer (to my taste).